# Does this endpoint belong to the Steam Web API?

Tags: steam-web-api

I've been looking for a way to get in-game information from the game Dead by Daylight, such as Characters, Perks, Items, etc. In my search, I found an [old GitHub Repository](https://github.com/Nexure/DBD-API), from which I was able to get a link to return a list of all the outfits from the in-game store:

https://steam.live.bhvrdbd.com/api/v1/extensions/store/getOutfits

*You have to anonymously login through https://steam.live.bhvrdbd.com/api/v1/auth/login/guest first to get a token... I think. It worked that way for me on Postman.*

What I'm confused about is what this endpoint even is. Steam Web API endpoints usually start like this:

https://api.steampowered.com/

So what is this seemingly DbD-specific API endpoint? Is it part of the Steam Web API? Or is this something different from before Steam Web API was even a thing or widely available to most developers? The game did come out in 2016 after all.

What is this endpoint and where can I find documentation about it?

Answer (score 0):

`bhvrdbd.com` is a private API used by the Dead by Daylight client, there is not any official documentation about it. You can however verify the ownership by opening the game while monitoring your outgoing network requests with for example [Fiddler](https://www.telerik.com/fiddler), and you will see that the game communicates with the domain mentioned:

[image]

The Steam API URL you mentioned are correct but unlike `bhvrdbd.com`, its purpose is letting third party developers not affiliated with Behaviour Interactive access game data.